# How can a spectrum object be constructed?

Tags: category-theory

There are so many spectrum objects in mathematics.

- spectrum of a linear operator
- spectrum of a ring
- spectrum of a graph
- spectrum in algebraic topology
- spectrum of a sentence (mathematical logic)

There has to be some universal property uniting all of these spectrum objects. How do you use a universal construction to derive each of the five?

Comment: The spectrum of a graph is the spectrum of a linear operator, and the fact that there is also a spectrum of ring is just a coincidence as far as I know. I doubt there's any concept underlying both cases.

Comment: @Arnaud D. There's also a spectrum in algebraic topology, so I don't think it's a coincidence.

Comment: Sounds like even more of a coincidence to me...

Comment: @ArnaudD Spectrum of a sentence (mathematical logic)

Comment: Did you get these examples from [this MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7389/what-are-the-most-overloaded-words-in-mathematics/7562#7562)? (Although Tom Leinster's comment shows that I was wrong in my first comment.)

Comment: @ArnaudD. No. Wikipedia.

Comment: Ok, I looked at some of the definitions and they do have more similarities than I thought. That's interesting.

Comment: There is a general notion of spectrum that might encompass (or be related to) some of your examples (the ones in logic I don't think so): [Isbell duality](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Isbell+duality)

Comment: Spectra in algebraic topology and spectra of sentences are _totally_ unrelated to the other notions of spectra you mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does not answer the question (I'd be surprised if there was a categorical way to define a "spectrum" which somehow encompasses the weird definitions in logic, topology, etc.) but it's a bit too long to be a comment.

It's a bit misleading to think of the first three constructions as the same universal construction going on in three different categories, because they are in fact the same construction in **one** category: the category of rings. (I wouldn't be surprised if the spectrum in the sense of topology is also the special case of the spectrum of a ring, but I don't know anything about that.)

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field (characteristic $0$ if you like), and $T$ a linear operator acting on a finite-dimensional $k$-vector space. Then $\operatorname{Spec} T$ is, by definition, the space of "generalized eigenvalues" (i.e. diagonal entries in the Jordan canonical form of $T$) with repetition. But if $\chi_T(x) \in k[x]$ is the characteristic polynomial of $T$ then the roots of $\chi_T(x)$ are precisely the generalized eigenvalues with repetition, so the affine scheme $\operatorname{Spec} k[x]/(\chi_T(x)) = \operatorname{Spec} T$ in a natural way: namely, its points are generalized eigenvalues of $T$, and we can recover their multiplicities as the dimension of the localization as a $k$-algebra. Therefore the spectrum of a ring is a generalization of a spectrum of a linear operator.

Since the "spectrum" of a graph is the spectrum of its adjacency matrix $M$, this is obviously a special case of the spectrum of a linear operator. So it is the spectrum of the ring $\mathbb C[x]/(\chi_M(x))$.

Comment: What is the universal property for JCF? "because they are in fact the same construction in one category: the category of rings." Why are vector spaces in the category of rings? They are in the category of R-modules?